# EL1021E: A problem occurred whilst attempting to access the property

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data, thymeleaf

I have a problem with access to field (username) of nested object (User) in another object (Lecture) in thymeleaf. But there is no problem with access to User's id.
Any ideas?

```
     @Entity
     public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        
        @NotBlank
        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String username;
    
        public User() {}
    
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
    
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
}
```

Lecture.java

```
    @Entity
    public class Lecture {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
    
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private User speaker;
    
        private String title;
    
        public Lecture() {
        }
        
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        
        public void setSpeaker(User speaker) {
            this.speaker = speaker;
        }
    
        public User getSpeaker() {
            return speaker;
        }
    }
```

Part of index.html

```
<tbody>
     <tr th:each="lecture : ${lecturesPage}">
         <td><a th:href="@{'/lecture/' + ${lecture.id}}" th:text="${lecture.id}"></a></td>
         <td th:text="${lecture.speaker.username}" /> <-- not working -->
         <td th:text="${lecture.speaker.id}" /> <-- working -->
         <td th:text="${lecture.title}" />
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Console:

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "lecture.speaker.username"

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1021E: A problem occurred whilst attempting to access the property 'username': 'Unable to access property 'username' through getter method'

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Unable to access property 'username' through getter method

Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.springbootlecturewebapp.springbootlecturewebapp.model.dao.User#1] - no Session

Answer (score 0):

Removed (fetch = FetchType.LAZY) is working

```
@Entity
    public class Lecture {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
    
        @ManyToOne // Removed (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private User speaker;
}
```